# Delaying filtering until button click with yadcf plug-in

Tags: jquery, yadcf

I want to prevent yadfc from applying any filtering until a certain click event happens - ie. the user would set the filter parameters and then click an 'apply filters' button - is there any way to only trigger the filtering manually via a click event?

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you are looking for the `externally_triggered: true` option, I've added this recently, see [externally_triggered showcase page](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_source_externally_triggered.html) (see code snippet in the bottom of the page) and see [relevant issue](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/141)

Code sample:

```
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable({...
 }).yadcf([
        {
            column_number : 0, 
            filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container_0',
        },
        {
            column_number : 1,
            filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container_1',
            filter_type: 'range_number_slider'
        },
        {
            column_number : 2,
            filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container_2',
            filter_type: 'range_date'
        },
      ],
      { 
        externally_triggered: true
      });
```